# How to implement UserStore.GetClaimsAsync method

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, usermanager

I have a custom user store that implements IUserClaimStore. That way, I need to implement GetClaimsAsync method, but I am stuck here.

This is my current implementation:

```
    public Task<IList<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync(T user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new List<Claim>());
    }
```

This is not valid since List does not implement IList. So the question is, how can I do it?

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: `List<T>` does implement `IList<T>` - that's not your problem.  Just assign the new `List<T>` to a local variable of type `IList<T>` before passing it to `FromResult`

Comment: @WillDean thanks! I could not imagine that I needed to assign a variable first. Now it works.